# How to trigger function specific period of time

Tags: java, spring, cron

I use @Scheduled cron to in my Java Spring project to trigger function every 5 seconds:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "*/5 * * * * *", zone = "US/Eastern")
public void schedule() throws Exception { some logic }
```

and it works perfectly.

I tried to trigger every 30 minutes:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 */30 * * * *", zone = "US/Eastern")
```

and this to trigger every hour minutes:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 1 * * *", zone = "US/Eastern")
```

But the two examples above don't work.

How can I configure cron to trigger the function every 30 minutes and every hour?

Comment: Shouldn't "every hour" be  `0 0 * * * *`? Afaik `0 0 1 * * *` would mean 1:00 am every day.

Comment: @Thomas thank you for the post!
In case if I want to trigger every 30 minutes it would be: " 0 30 * * * *"

Comment: Well, it depends on whether "every 30 minutes" means "xx:30" or an interval of 30 minutes, e.g. "xx:00" _and_ "xx:30".

Comment: @Thomas in case I want to trigger every 30 minutes of the hour, for ex: 1pm, 1.30pm, 2pm and...

Comment: Well, the pattern for that should be as you set it. Alternatives: `0 0/30 * * * *` (every 30 minutes starting at 0) or `0 0,30 * * * *` (at minute 0 and 30)